# Panorama scrolls back to first item when another view is updated

Tags: windows-phone-8, panorama-control

I have found a strange issue with my windows phone 8 application using a panorama control.

Each panorama item is created dynamically using a templateselector and view models as itemsource.

In one of the panorama items I have a Listpicker. Once it's activated the panorama control scrolls back to the first panorama item. I was able to temporary fix the problem by setting the height of the view to 1000. Unfortunately, the same issue occurs when I set a hidden loading view visible.

It seems as the problem occurs when the layout is updated?

Any ideas on what could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Without any code it is hard to tell.  But it seems kinda similar to one I answer awhile back:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016287/windows-phone-8-add-frameworkelement-to-panoramaitem-from-code-behind/25019860#25019860

Comment: Thanks, that solved one of the issues. Found the problem with the loading view. It was due to a ProgressBar that was wider than PanoramItem. The Panorama Control did not like that...